# Needs to Add Instagram in Beautifo WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, customization

I have just purchase a new theme for my beauty shop ([Beautifo theme](https://themeforest.net/item/beautifo-beauty-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/31883250)) from Themelexus author.
And now i don't know I would like to add Instagram in our website. Anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget you can add of Instagram to your theme. Also, you can add FB too. It will have live photos.

Answer (score 0):

I see this theme supports by Elementor. You can use Elementor to add a widget and import Instagram to your theme.
I checked theme guide, you can follow: https://wpdocs.gitbook.io/beautifo/faq/faqs/how-to-add-instagram-in-wordpress

You can add for yourself or ask theme provider to get urgent support.
Thanks